# Create List of int and str from a date

Tags: python, string, list, date, int

I am trying to learn python and I have an exercise where I should create a List out of a date, like so:
Date is formatted to: %m %H %A (month, hour, day of week)

List should contain: (month as int, hour as int, day of week as str)

I have no clue how to do that. Can someone please help?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to work a bit for your answers! there are tons of tutorials and posts here on SO that will guide you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they're separated by spaces as they are in your question in the form

```
string = '{} {} {}'.format(str(month), str(hour), day)
```

i.e. `'11 13 Monday'`

You can use the `str.split`:

```
month, hour, day = string.split(' ')
month = int(month); hour = int(hour)
```

Comment: FYI you won't learn Python by asking the answer to a specific question. I'm sure the purpose of the assignment was to research python types and their methods.